# PHP - printf() prints part of my code

Tags: php, html, output, quotes

When running this (simple) code:

```
<?php

$array = array("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "");

foreach ($array as $arrayElement) {
    printf("<div class = \"colorSubArea %s \" > <p> 1 </p> </div> " , $arrayElement);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xbkky7jx/3/

the last part of my code is geting printed out. Also the loop doesn't continue after the first iteration (possibly the same cause).I am new in PHP and this is very confusing to me.

Comment: Perhaps because your webserver (like jsfiddle) isn't set up to execute PHP

Comment: Because JSfiddle doesn't do server side code. You need to test PHP code with a service that will execute the code on the server side.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/058493d6ce9e2cef0b626c07a2e4494953b640c3

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker.

Comment: Apache absent of the `php` module would the same; serve the file without parser-logic.

Comment: You could use XAMPP to run your PHP code. It's a pretty neat tool and free.

Comment: Are you sure JSFiddle can interpret the PHP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your php code is ok, the reason you don't see the output is HTML, see the output in `viewsource` mode.

Your output is:

```
<div class = "colorSubArea Blue " > <p> 1 </p> </div> 
<div class = "colorSubArea Green " > <p> 1 </p> </div> 
<div class = "colorSubArea Yellow " > <p> 1 </p> </div> 
<div class = "colorSubArea Pink " > <p> 1 </p> </div> 
<div class = "colorSubArea  " > <p> 1 </p> </div>
```

see this:
https://eval.in/568890

```
          $array = array("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink", "");

          foreach($array as $arrayElement){  
            printf("%s " , $arrayElement);
          }
```